# Chrome Dev Tools not detecting Nexus 5x Android 8 device

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, android-8.0-oreo, nexus-5x

I've been following this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

I'm trying to remote debug my node.js site on localhost:3000 using my phone, but no devices are showing up under the remote devices tab. Discover USB devices, port forwarding, network targets are all checked. I've added a rule for localhost:3000 under port forwarding along with localhost:3000 as an address under network targets.  I've tried going to localhost:3000 on my phone in chrome, but I just get the "site can't be reached" page.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, using Chromium Version 63 with Nexus 5x Android 8. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Type chrome://inspect/#devices on your google chrome, then connect the cable and unblock the mobile, go to the usb options, select "Transfer files", go to your pc and try to open the internal storage... at this point the mobile will ask for debug authorization. Authorize and it's done! 
Dont forget to enable all need